# If I love my job (and company), but my role has been stripped of responsibilities, what will I gain from staying?

Tags: management, career-development, quitting

(*I think my previous questions were not clear or comprehensive enough as I always get negative rating or incomplete answers. So let me try again, as this question is really important to me.*)

I truly love my job, believe in the company, invested and sacrificed a lot in the projects that have shaped it to become what it is today. However, some new organizational changes have led to me losing most of my managerial responsibilities, and a person closer to senior management has been groomed (and now confirmed) to become head of my team.

I am already excluded from strategically important meetings, am given tasks without knowing the rationale and generally am less involved in decision-making.

As I have been a top performer and always got only positive feedback in my reviews since I joined the company as a junior manager, I believe the reasons for this are political rather than my own performance or skills.

In any case, I would find it sad to leave. On the one hand, I don't want to work with less responsibilities because my ultimate goal is to gain experience towards senior management. On the other hand, I really believe in the potential of my company, I know it is growing fast and what we have done so far is nearly unprecedented in business. So, I have mixed feelings about leaving.

As my future is uncertain (not sure if I could be made redundant; not sure if I will ever get further opportunities to grow; not sure what the next reorganization could mean for me; very unlikely to grow salary, etc.) I am struggling to find good *practical/non-spiritual* reasons to stay, but I feel that if I *did* stay and all went well, I would feel more fulfilled in terms of witnessing how everything I started evolves and see how the company fares.

So... in my situation, what are the advantages of staying rather than quitting?

Comment: I don't see any way to answer this in a way that is generally applicable rather than something that is specific to just you.  That makes it impossible to answer in this sort of forum.  Only you can weigh your feelings, your situation, your options, and come to a decision that is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing: the only thing someone can steal from you that they can't pay back is your time.  There are plenty of companies worthy of your time, and plenty that are not.

Weigh the benefits of staying and going.

Staying:

1. Can you arrange a transfer to a different job in the company? You
   want to gain the chops to be an executive. You will learn a lot by
   working in product management or as a customer-facing expert.
2. Do you have stock options or an equity share which will vest in a
   short time? If so, that's a reason to stay until you vest. Then
   exercise your options and go. You'll still have a stake in the
   company's success. You'll be a shareholder so they will send you
   annual reports. If they sell or go public, you'll share in that.
3. Is your pay more than satisfactory? That's a reason to stay, but not
   a great one. (What money is your time worth?)
4. Are your benefits hard to match elsewhere?
5. Do you have particular loyalties to certain *people* in the company?
   Are those loyalties returned?  If so, consider staying. (Notice that
   I'm mentioning personal relationships, not generalized loyalty to
   the company.)
6. Do you think the recently recruited management realistically might
   fail? (It happens sometimes, especially when new managers
   deliberately waste the talents of long-time employees.) If so, your
   presence might help the company recover after that.

Going:

1. Are there other companies where you will learn more?
2. Are there other companies where you will have a better quality of work life?
3. Are there other companies where you can really make a difference to their success, as you have in the past at your present company?

I think it's likely that your scale will tip towards "go," but maybe not.  The good news is this: if you decide to go you have time now to find an excellent job without rushing.

Comment: Thank you Ollie Jones. Your question 5 - Yes, I have very strong bonds, especially with my first manager and others I have worked with since I started (currently I work less with them day-to-day, but they are the backbone of my team). I also had the impression that a very few in senior management care about me.
Despite these loyalties (AND the loyalty to the company), my fear is that if I stay without learning anything new, I could easily get redundant. Although I'm an expert in my field, I trained my reports very well; they can execute without me and the new boss might not need another boss.

Comment: As for the other questions: Pay is low compared to industry, but as I have strong feelings for the work I have done (It's like "my baby", you know what I mean?) and it is well integrated with my life priorities - work/life balance is almost perfect.
To sum up all, questions 4 and 5 are in my favor, the rest are not.
And as for the other companies, I will need to do a lot of research before I can confirm anything.

Comment: You have a lot of creative working life ahead of you. Don't get too attached to one project. It's OK to finish your work in one place and move along. It's good you have a team of loyal peers: you may be able to team up somewhere else in the future to do another good thing.